# I am having trouble with OpenMP on C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize the for loops and I can't seem to grasp the concept, every time I try to parallelize them it still works but it slows down dramatically.

```
for(i=0; i<nbodies; ++i){
    for(j=i+1; j<nbodies; ++j) {
        d2 = 0.0;   
        
        for(k=0; k<3; ++k) {
            
            rij[k] = pos[i][k] - pos[j][k];
            
            d2 += rij[k]*rij[k];
        
        if (d2 <= cut2) {
           d = sqrt(d2);
           d3 = d*d2;
           
           for(k=0; k<3; ++k) {
                double f = -rij[k]/d3;
                forces[i][k] += f;
                forces[j][k] -= f;
           }
           
           ene += -1.0/d; 
        }
       }
    }
}
```

I tried using synchronization with barrier and critical in some cases but nothing happens or the processing simply does not end.

Update, this is the state I'm at right now. Working without crashes but calculation times worsen the more threads I add. (Ryzen 5 2600 6/12)

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(d,d2,d3,nbodies,rij,pos,cut2,forces) private(i,j,k) num_threads(n)
    {
        clock_t begin = clock();
       #pragma omp for schedule(auto)
        for(i=0; i<nbodies; ++i){
            
            for(j=i+1; j<nbodies; ++j) {
                d2 = 0.0;
                for(k=0; k<3; ++k) {
                    rij[k] = pos[i][k] - pos[j][k];
                    d2 += rij[k]*rij[k];    
                }
                
                if (d2 <= cut2) {
                    d = sqrt(d2);
                    d3 = d*d2;
                #pragma omp parallel for shared(d3) private(k) schedule(auto) num_threads(n)
                 for(k=0; k<3; ++k) {
                    double f = -rij[k]/d3;
                    #pragma omp atomic 
                    forces[i][k] += f;
                    #pragma omp atomic
                    forces[j][k] -= f;
                    }
                    
                    ene += -1.0/d; 
                }
            }
        }
    
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        #pragma omp single
        printf("Calculation time %lf sec\n",time_spent);
    }
```

I incorporated the timer in the actual parallel code (I think it is some milliseconds faster this way). Also I think I got most of the shared and private variables right. In the file it outputs the forces.

Comment: If you ask a question regarding code in a specific language, please don't tag other languages. While they might seem similar, C and C++ are in fact two *very* different languages. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  The above code is missing declarations and also how you attempted to parallelize the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, turns out all I needed was

```
#pragma omp parallel for nowait
```

Doesn't need the "atomic" either.

Weird solution, I don't fully understand how it works but it does also the output file has 0 corrupt results whatsoever.

Comment: Note that your OpenMP implementation has several problems (e.g. data race). If it accidentally gives the correct result, it does not mean that your code is correct.

Comment: I think it covers what I was aiming for, I tested it many times and I didn't get any errors. Surely it probably doesn't apply to other similar problems but it worked for me so...

"If it aint broke dont fix it" - some wise guy

Answer (score 1):

Using barriers or other synchronizations will slow down your code, if the amount of unsynchronized work is not larger by a good factor. That is not the case with you. You probably need to reformulate your code to remove synchronization.

You are doing something like an N-body simulation. I've worked out a couple of solutions here: [https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-examples.html#N-bodyproblems](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-examples.html#N-bodyproblems)

Also: your `d2` loop is a reduction, so you can treat it like that, but it is probably enough if that variable is private to the `i,j` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You should always define your variables in their minimal required scope, especially if performance is an issue. (Note that if you do so your compiler can create more efficient code). Besides performance it also helps to avoid data race.

I think you have misplaced a curly brace and the condition in the first `for` loop should be `i<nbodies-1`. Variable `ene` can be summed up using reduction and to avoid data race atomic operations have to be used to increase array `forces`, so you do not need to use slow barriers or critical sections. Your code should look something like this (assuming `int` for indices and `double` for calculation):

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ene)
 for(int i=0; i<nbodies-1; ++i){
    for(int j=i+1; j<nbodies; ++j) {
        double d2 = 0.0;       
        double rij[3];
        for(int k=0; k<3; ++k) {
            rij[k] = pos[i][k] - pos[j][k];            
            d2 += rij[k]*rij[k];       
        }
        if (d2 <= cut2) {
           double d = sqrt(d2);
           double d3 = d*d2;
           
           for(int k=0; k<3; ++k) {
                double f = -rij[k]/d3;
                #pragma omp atomic
                forces[i][k] += f;
                #pragma omp atomic
                forces[j][k] -= f;
           }           
           ene += -1.0/d;         
       }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: The variables are declared before the loops here
`double (*pos)[3], (*forces)[3];
 double rij[3], d, d2, d3, ene, cut2=1000.0;
 unsigned i, j, k, nbodies;`

Comment: Also when I decrease the number of threads it crashes I really am at a stalemate here.

Comment: To find out the cause of crashes, please provide a [mre].

Comment: I managed to get it running without errors by setting the private and shared variables.
But it is still slower than serial processing and when I increase the number of threads, the calculation time increases. I also noticed that the output is corrupted when I use more than 1 thread, resulting in data not being calculated which means I have to synchronize it somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean your code is not working properly or the one I show you here? Most probably you have a data race. Please understand that we cannot help you until you show us exactly how you parallelized your code. To find the performance issue even more details are needed,  which can be provided by a [mre].